# WIndows Phone 7.1 SDK vs Windows Phone 7.5 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7

What is the difference between **Windows Phone 7.1 (NoDo)** and **Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango)**?

I have installed the SDK for Mango but when I try to create a project it shows me as version 7.1!

Are these two versions the same?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, no, NoDo version was 7.0, if I recall correctly. Mango is 7.5, but SDK for Mango has version 7.1. Just go on with 7.1, it will work perfectly.

Comment: Please mark this response as the Answer, 7.0 was release and a patch to the OS was NoDo but didn't change the Development version 7.0.

Development version 7.1 is exactly the same as the OS version 7.5 which is Mango.

So you develop in 7.0 (release and Nodo) or you can develop in 7.1 (7.5 mango) for the Windows Phone at current.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing much of a difference as far as technical perspective is concerned. 7.1 is the sdk version and 7.5 is the device version. The management went ahead with the product by calling it as 7.5 just as a marketing perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Those two versions are definitely the same. NoDo was released as a small update to 7.0 that did not change much. When the first beta of the Mango SDK was released it still wasn't clear what the version number would be. People expected 7.5 but it was called the 7.1 SDK. Right now marketing is always speaking about WP7.5, but in essence it's just 7.1 Either way, 7.0 is compatible with NoDo and before, 7.1 is only compatible with Mango.

Answer (score 0):

NoDo version is 7.0.73..
Mango O.S version is 7.10.7720.68
Software version is Windows Phone 7.5